# Finding and sorting data from an unsorted MySQL table / multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | app_id | field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | 9 | First Name |
| xxx | yyy | 2 | Last Name |

The "value" column contains data like First Name, Last Name, Adress, E-Mail and so on. The only way to identify what kind of value is situated in the "value" column, is by the "field_id". Meanwhile the "app_id" acts as an unique identifier for the user / a User ID.
(The table is provided by a WordPress Plugin, therefore however terrible it might be I cannot change this.)

This means to get First name and last name of an user I would have to search for 2 rows with the same app_id and then get the value column where the field_id is 9 for first name and 2 for last name.

So what I wanna print out is something like: (pseudo code)

```
for ($app_id) {
 if (app_id == $app_id && field_id = 9) {
   $first_name = value
 }
 if (app_id == $app_id && field_id = 2) {
   $last_name = value
 }
echo $first_name . $last_name;
}
```

So far I only have the following code, which puts all the data in a multidimensional array:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","dbane","dbpass","dbuser");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
$fields = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM name_of_table");
$results = $fields->fetch_all();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        /* Lost what to do here */
    }
}
```

How would I go about getting the first name and last name of each user and put them together?

The database contains about 20.000 rows so using multiple mysqli_queries is not an option as the load time is 10min.+ and puts a terrible load on the server.

Comment: _Small Point_ All MySQL tables are unsorted

Comment: Well ___Step 1___) `SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE app_id = 'yyy'`

Comment: Then ___Step 2)___ `SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE app_id = 'yyy' and (field_id = 9 OR field_id = 2)` Now you are only processing the 2 rows you actually want instead of the whole table

Comment: ___PS___ If that was a stretch, you really need to stop and spend a few hours working through some BASIC SQL Tutorials

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This was not a stretch at all, I even have a solution exactly like this. However I need to sort through about 20.000 rows of data and I need to not only get 2 values but 8. This means 8 of these calls going through the whole database table

Comment: Ok 8 why? 8 whats?

Comment: I only used first and last name as examples. There are a total of 8 values (first name, last name, email, phone no., and so on) with different field IDs. Doing 8 seperate SELECT calls on the big database leads to a load time of at least 10 minutes. This is why I figured getting everything just once and sorting through a PHP array would greatly reduce the load time and server load

Comment: So `WHERE app_id = 'yyy' AND field_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` and now you have the 8 you want ONLY and just have to write a SWITCH to place the bits in the right variables Or stick with your IF's if you prefer

Comment: You could `GROUP BY app-id` and `ORDER BY field_id ASC` which wouldngive you what you want.

Comment: @Sherif only wants one app_id returned, and sorting would make it look nice, but you woudl still have to test `field_id` to know what actual value was in which returned row

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing the following, with the help of RiggsFolly:

```
    for ($i = $count; $i >= ($count - 1000); $i--) {
        $data = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE app_id = $i AND field_id IN (2,9,15,5,10,11,6,3)");
        $names = $data->fetch_all();
        foreach ($names as list($a, $b, $c, $d)) {
            switch ($c)
                case 9:
                    $first_name = $d;
                    break:
                case 15:
                    $last_name = $d;
                    break;
        }
    }
```